# Book about a boy who goes back in time from his kitchen and becomes an apprentice under a famous painter

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read a book in 2000-2002.

It starts off with a boy sitting in a kitchen while his mom leaves for a date. He watches TV and is somehow transported through time, each time he goes back further, until he reaches medieval times and gets stuck. He then becomes an apprentice under a famous painter. He secretly starts to paint his kitchen hundreds of times until he gets every detail right and is then immediately transported back into the kitchen at the beginning of the story.

I also remember the author's last name to be of Eastern European descent and most likely male.